# ${CALLERID(RDNIS)} not able to get redirected dialled number in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, phone-number, ivr

I have this situation where I have 2 numbers say A and B which is forwarded to same DID number so the issue is that I want to identify if the call is forwarded from A or B when the caller calls in to specific number.

I have researched a bit and found about [`${CALLERID(rdnis)}`](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/RDNIS) in asterisk but when am trying to use it gives a blank output. I also tried the `DumpChan()` command it also gave a `(N/A)` for rdnis.

**Is there any way I can get to know in my dialplan that call is forwarded from A or B ?**

**I dont have sip my line is normal PSTN. The problem is that the number mentioned in the question A and B are mobile number which are forwarded to DID number and I can only control the code after the DID is called but I cannot identify through which number A or B the call is forwarded on DID.**

Comment: How is DID termination done? Do you have control over dialplan between the moments A/B numbers arrives to you PBX and redirection to extension is made?

Comment: I can only control dialplan after DID is called

Comment: Never found a way to do that. When I have to identify forwarding number I buy many cheap DIDs and forward every line to its own DID.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is sip, you can do

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```

After that call in. If you see forwarded number in packet, you can try get it using SIP_HEADER function.
If there is no any difference in two calls, you can't recognize did and better use cheap voip did for second number.

Comment: I dont have sip my line is normal PSTN. The problem is that the number mentioned in the question A and B are mobile number which are forwarded to DID number and I can only control the code after the DID is called and But I cannot identify through which number A or B the call is forwarded on DID.

Comment: You can't. You can get other sip did and forward to it. PSTN= wire, single line, no info.